# What are Riemann Matrix?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

I got this information regarding Riemann matrix:

RIEMANN is a N-by-N matrix associated with the Riemann hypothesis, which is true if and only if:

```
 DET(A) = O( N! N^(-1/2+epsilon) ) for every epsilon>0 ('!' denotes factorial).
 where, A= Riemann matrix
```

with,

```
  A = B(2:N+1, 2:N+1),
```

where

```
  B(i,j) = i-1 if i divides j and
           -1 otherwise.
```

Properties include, with M = N+1:

1. Each eigenvalue E(i) satisfies ABS(E(i)) <= M - 1/M.
2. i <= E(i) <= i+1 with at most M-SQRT(M) exceptions.
3. All integers in the interval (M/3, M/2] are eigenvalues.

Reference: F. Roesler, Riemann's hypothesis as an eigenvalue problem, Linear Algebra and Appl., 81 (1986), pp. 153-198.

[Link to the Reference Paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379586902557)

Now, I have a Matlab Function which creates a 3-by-3 Riemann matrix as:

```
    R=riemann(3)
```

R=

```
 1    -1     1
-1     2    -1
-1    -1     3
```

and

```
 eig(R)
```

ans =

```
0.5858
2.0000
3.4142
```

Questions:

1. What is "O" factor in the meaning of determinant ?
2. How do the 3-by-3 Riemann matrix "R" created by my function concur with properties stated above ? (1st property holds good but other two ??)

P.S.: If u need to take a look at my function,please tell me.